# Cancel sale and remove from sale history

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a post sale application using sql dbase, it is running fluently my issue with canceling sale and remove entry from sale history and database. the following code suppose to do that but it does exactly the contrairy it adds

```
private void btnVoid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtUsername.Text.ToLower() == cancelOrder.txtCancelBy.Text.ToLower())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Void by name and cancelled by name are same!. Please void by another person.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }
            string user;
            cn.Open();
            cm = new SqlCommand("Select * From tbUser Where username = @username and password = @password", cn);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPass.Text);
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                user = dr["username"].ToString();
                dr.Close();
                cn.Close();
                SaveCancelOrder(user);
                if(cancelOrder.cboInventory.Text=="yes")
                {
                    dbcon.ExecuteQuery("UPDATE tbProduct SET qty = qty + " + cancelOrder.udCancelQty.Value + " where pcode= '" + cancelOrder.txtPcode.Text + "'");
                }
                dbcon.ExecuteQuery("UPDATE tbCart SET qty = qty + " + cancelOrder.udCancelQty.Value + " where id LIKE '" + cancelOrder.txtId.Text + "'");
                MessageBox.Show("Order transaction successfully cancelled!", "Cancel Order", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                this.Dispose();
                cancelOrder.ReloadSoldList();
                cancelOrder.Dispose();

            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        }
    }
```

I could not figure out the the problem.

Comment: Please read up on SQL injection. You should use parameterized queries.

Comment: You seem to be reseting the Product and Cart quantity but never deleting the entry from the Sales table.

Comment: Can you help modify the posted code and correct that function? ty

Comment: after canceling the sale with succssess msg, the stock base increase with number entred that supposed to be deleted and canceled.

Comment: I am not familiar with your database structure but you can do something like this.
`"DELETE FROM (replace with SalesTable) WHERE ID = '"+cancelOrder.txtId.Text"'`

Comment: "DELETE FROM (replace with SalesTable) WHERE ID = '"+cancelOrder.txtId.Text"' did not change anything

Comment: @Izanagi Noooo! **NEVER** suggest someone use string concatenation.

Comment: Yikes, not only SQL injection issues, but plain text passwords. I would NOT want code like this anywhere in my environement.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I totally agree with you but the code I provided was supposed to be something of a general idea to what he could do.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem easly by replacing " + " with "-", thats it.

```
dbcon.ExecuteQuery("UPDATE tbCart SET qty = qty - " + cancelOrder.udCancelQty.Value + " where id LIKE '" + cancelOrder.txtId.Text + "'");
```

Comment: It's still **crazy-vulnerable** to sql injection issues. You should be using a _query parameter_ instead of string concatenation to include the cancel quantity.